# SQL Server : Insert Multiple Rows into Multiple Tables From Table Type Paramater

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to write a stored procedure which takes in a table type parameter and inserts into two tables at once.

I have an entity table which is a base table holding the id for various tables, below is the entity table and a sample Site table.

```
------ Entity Table ------------------------------------------
| Id              | bigint        | NOT NULL | IDENTITY(1,1) | PRIMARY KEY
| TypeId          | tinyint       | NOT NULL | 
| Updated         | datetime      | NULL     | 
| Created         | datetime      | NOT NULL | 
| IsActive        | bit           | NOT NULL | 

------- Site Table ---------------------------------------
| EntityId        | bigint        | NOT NULL | PRIMARY KEY
| ProductTypeCode | nvarchar(8)   | NOT NULL | PRIMARY KEY 
| SupplierCode    | nvarchar(8)   | NOT NULL | PRIMARY KEY
| Name            | nvarchar(128) | NOT NULL | 
| Description     | nvarchar(max) | NULL     |
```

And here is my table type used to pass into the stored procedure

```
------- Site Table Type ----------------------------------
| EntityTypeId    | tinyint       | NOT NULL |
| ProductTypeCode | nvarchar(8)   | NOT NULL | PRIMARY KEY
| SupplierCode    | nvarchar(8)   | NOT NULL | PRIMARY KEY
| Name            | nvarchar(128) | NOT NULL |
| Description     | nvarchar(max) | NULL     |
```

The idea is that I will pass in a table type parameter into the stored procedure and insert multiple rows at once to save looping inserting one row at a time.

Here's what I have so far

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertSites
    @Sites SiteTypeTable READONLY
AS
BEGIN

-- Insert into Entity & Site Tables here, using the Id from the Entity Table in the Site table

    INSERT INTO Entity (TypeId, Updated, Created, IsActive)
    OUTPUT [inserted].[Id], S.ProductTypeCode, S.SupplierCode, S.Name, S.Description
    INTO Site
    SELECT EntityTypeId, NULL, GETDATE(), 1
    FROM @Sites S

END
```

I've read about using insert and output together but cannot get this to work. I've also read about merge but also cannot get this to work.

Any help or pointers you can give will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Neil

---- Edit ----

Could I do something like this? I'm not sure how to finish this off...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertSites
    @Sites SiteTypeTable READONLY
AS
BEGIN

    -- First insert enough rows into Entity table, saving the inserted Ids to a table variable

    DECLARE @InsertedOutput TABLE (EntityId bigint)

    INSERT INTO Entity (TypeId, Updated, Created, IsActive)
    OUTPUT [inserted].[id]
    INTO @InsertedOutput
    SELECT EntityTypeId, NULL, GETDATE(), 1
    FROM @Sites S

    -- Use the Ids in @InsertedOutput against the rows in @Sites to insert into Sites

END
```

Comment: Inserting data into two tables will require you to write TWO Insert statements, You can warp both insert statements inside One transaction. But you cannot insert data in two tables with one insert statement.

Comment: @M.Ali even with something like my edit using insert and output

Comment: OUTPUT clause will give you access to inserted table. Inserted table will only have values that were actually inserted into EntityTable. Again Like I said before you will need to write another Insert statement to insert data into Site table.